# What to do after violation of homogeneity of regression in ANCOVA

Tags: data-transformation, assumptions, ancova

I wanted to run an ANCOVA. My independent variable is field of study (3 groups: science, humanities, and business). My dependent variable is IQ measured on a continuous scale. There are two covariates: years of education (continuous variable) and sex (categorical variable). However when I tested the ANCOVA assumptions I found that the homogeneity of regression assumption was violated. What should I run instead of ANCOVA? I remember reading somewhere that one thing I can maybe do is a transformation of the covariate(s). Is that a good solution? If so, can anyone point me to some online resource on how to do it?
I think I also recall hearing something about an aligned ranks transformation. Would that work?
Or any other options?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

I oppose transforming variables just to meet the assumptions of a model.

You could try robust regression, or quantile regression.

If your subjects are professionals in those three fields, there might also be collinearity. It would be good to know who your subjects are.

Education in years of education might be a bit problematic. Once you get past high school (12 years, usually, but not always -- e.g. I skipped 12th grade) it gets very tricky. What if you do 2 years of college, then drop out, then go back (LOTS of people do this).  And different graduate degrees take different lengths of time and, as many here will know too well, a PhD can vary a lot in how long  it takes.

Comment: Thanks very much! I will look into the two regression methods you mentioned. And have definitely taken into account the other issues you brought up already.